# How can I disable DLC suggestions?

Tags: rocksmith-2014

Today, suddenly these adverts popped up in my song list:
[image: ingame ads]

Since I really dislike adverts in games, especially non-F2P-games, how can I disable them? I think they came with an update...

Comment: Similarly, it's totally ridiculous that Ubisoft advertises availability new *payable* DLC in game as "update". Annoying.

Comment: @Andalur - Hey, did Kodama's answer work for you? If so, remember to mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 2):

While there is no option in game to turn of the DLC suggestions, they won't appear when you start Rocksmith offline. On PC, you can start the game in Steam's offline mode and on consoles without signing in to PSN or Xbox Live to get rid of the suggestions.

The only disadvantage will be that Leaderboards won't work and you can't access the store until you are signed in.

Answer (score 1):

New DLC is released every week, and this basically shows the list of titles for the current week. It's more informative than the other way new DLC is mentioned in game because it lists the specific tracks available.

The other way DLC is mentioned is as follows:

- The main-screen has an Ubisoft controlled message in the same place as the current missions.
- It was used for a "season's greeting" message over the Christmas period.
- However it usually mentions the musician/band that has new DLC in the current week.

Currently there's no way to turn either off. (Someone even reported that buying the DLC left two entries: one for the advert, and one for the purchased item.)

Personally, I like it.
If new DLC is released for a band I like, I can find out about it without searching the on-line store or going to the [forums](http://forums.ubi.com/forumdisplay.php/560-Rocksmith-DLC). Basically it's an alternate source of information. And at a maximum of 8 listings in a week, I don't find it intrusive. (If it were more I would feel differently though.)